# how can ı remove(delete) empty lines in my script or let say text with codes? is it possible

Tags: python, scripting

ı am new in coding. ı have searched on the net but ı couldn't find any suitable answer. as far as ı learned ı have reached this point but it is working in the wrong way. so ı would like to learn whether is it possible to delete specific line or lines in blender python. Thanks in advance.

```
def execute(self, context):
    scene = context.scene
    mytool = scene.my_tool
    txt = mytool.my_strng
    ec= mytool.my_bool4 
    
    i = bpy.data.texts['fake text'].current_line_index
    i = 0 
    while i < 120: 
        try: 
            if bpy.data.texts[str(txt)].lines[i].body == '':
                bpy.ops.text.select_line()
                bpy.ops.text.delete(type='PREVIOUS_CHARACTER')
                bpy.ops.text.delete(type='NEXT_CHARACTER')
            i = i+1
        except IndexError:
            return {'FINISHED'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First check index of the lines you want to delete

```
import bpy

def del_line(text, i):
    print("you need delete line ", i)

text    = bpy.data.texts["text"]
lines   = text.lines

for i in range(len(lines) -1, -1, -1):
    l       = lines[i]
    body    = l.body
    width   = len(body) - 1
    if not body:
        del_line(text, i)
    elif body[0] * width == " " * width:
        del_line(text, i)
    elif width == 0 and body[0] == "\n":
        del_line(text, i)
```

### Then set the Text cursor, select the line and delete.

1 Run script

```
import bpy

def del_line(lines, i):
    print("you need delete line ", i)
    if lines[i].body:
        bpy.ops.text.jump(line = i + 1)    # Jump cursor to line
        bpy.ops.text.select_line()
        bpy.ops.text.delete()

    bpy.ops.text.jump(line = i + 1)
    bpy.ops.text.select_line()
    bpy.ops.text.delete()


class MyOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "text.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "My operator"

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        print("INVOKE")
        if context.area.type != 'TEXT_EDITOR':
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "Text Editor area only, cancelled")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        space   = context.space_data
        text    = space.text
        lines   = text.lines

        for i in range(len(lines) -1, -1, -1):
            l       = lines[i]
            body    = l.body
            width   = len(body) - 1
            if not body:
                del_line(lines, i)
            elif body[0] * width == " " * width:
                del_line(lines, i)
            elif width == 0 and body[0] == "\n":
                del_line(lines, i)

        return {'FINISHED'}


addon_keymaps = []
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyOperator)

    # Add the hotkey
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Text', space_type='TEXT_EDITOR')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new("text.modal_operator", type='F9', value='PRESS', ctrl=True)
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyOperator)

    # Remove the hotkey
    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

2 Press `Ctrl` `F9` in Text Editor

[image]

### Result

[image]

Comment: ı am trying to resolve it now thanks a lot

Comment: thank you again can you also just please explain a little bit about the second part which is setting cursor selecting line and delete. ı have tried a lot before disturbing you but couldn't. sorry for my ignorance

Comment: I updated a operator version.

Comment: That's very finely worked for me thanks a lot. except for short cut. I don't know why but the 'run script' pops up. but nothing happens. But from the operator itself, it worked very finely.